# Are these notions of group object with weak inverses equivalent?

Tags: ct.category-theory, gr.group-theory

This is a follow-up to [The definition of a group object is wrong?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66474/the-definition-of-a-group-object-is-wrong). The basic setup is as follows. Let $C$ be a category with finite products, $S : C \to D$ a product-preserving faithful functor, and $G \in C$ be a monoid object. It sometimes happens that $G$ has inverses in the sense that there exists a morphism $S(i) : S(G) \to S(G)$ making $S(G)$ a group object in $D$, but that this morphism does not lift to a morphism in $C$.

<strike>**Example:** A Poisson-Lie group with nontrivial Poisson bracket is not a group object in the category of Poisson manifolds $C$. However, it is a group object in the category $D$ of smooth manifolds; the inverse map negates the Poisson bracket, so does not lift to a Poisson map.</strike> (Not an example; see the comments.)

In the above question, Ryan Reich suggested two suitably weak notions of group object (in which the inverse is required to be a morphism) which allow the above example. Here they are, with ad hoc names for the sake of discussion.

> A *$D$-virtual group object* in $C$ is a monoid object $G \in C$ together with a morphism $S(i) : S(G) \to S(G)$ such that $S(G)$ is a group object in $D$ with $S(i)$ as the inverse.
>
> Let $F : C \to C$ be a functor such that $SF \cong S$. An *$(F, D)$-virtual group object* in $C$ is a monoid object $G \in C$ together with a morphism $i : G \to F(G)$ such that $S(G)$ is a group object in $D$ with $S(i)$ as the inverse.

The first definition is the most general one suggested by the basic setup, but the second definition suffices, at least, for the case of Poisson manifolds, where $F$ negates the Poisson bracket.

**Question 1:** Is every $D$-virtual group object actually an $(F, D)$-virtual group object for some $F$?

I expect the answer to be "no," but I don't know how I would go about constructing a counterexample. A basic observation is that $S(i)^2 = \text{id}_{S(G)}$, so the types of morphisms that can actually occur in $D$ as inverses are somewhat restricted: while they are "virtual morphisms" (Ben Webster suggested the term *heteromorphism*) in $C$, they must square to "real morphisms." A sufficiently good theory of heteromorphisms might make it possible to construct $F$ given $C, D, S$.

Various follow-up questions suggest themselves.

**Question 2:** Given $C, D, S$ as above, is there a unique $F$ such that $C$ admits $(F, D)$-virtual group objects which don't lift to group objects in $C$?

**Question 3:** Given a category $C$, how can I tell if it admits $D$-virtual group objects for some $D$ which don't lift to group objects in $C$?

**Question 4:** Can we describe heteromorphisms in a manner internal to $C$? (For example, if $C = \text{Cat}$, it seems a heteromorphism ought to be a contravariant functor. Here we can take $D$ to be the category of graphs, $S : C \to D$ the obvious forgetful functor, and $F$ the opposite category functor. Did we need to do this, or does the notion of contravariant functor naturally fall out of the structure of $C$ in some way?)

Comment: It seems that "virtual group" is also the name of a concept due to Mackey. Anyone have any other suggestions? I can't think of anything else particularly snappy. 

Comment: I think "product" is not the word you want in the first paragraph.  For example, given two Poisson manifolds, there is a canonical Poisson structure on the product of underlying manifolds.  But the thus-constructed Poisson manifold is not the categorical product of the first two Poisson manifolds in the category of Poisson manifolds.  (This is a semiclassical shadow of the fact that the tensor product of commutative rings is their coproduct in commutative rings, but the tensor product of noncommutative rings is not a coproduct.)

Comment: Indeed, you can see that the "Poisson product" is not the categorical product because there does not exist a diagonal map. Let $(M,\pi)$ be a Poisson manifold. The "product" $(M,\varpi)\otimes (M,\varpi)$ is the manifold $M\times M$ with Poisson structure $\varpi\oplus0\oplus\varpi$ (identifying $T^{\otimes 2}_{m,n}(M\times N) = T^{\otimes 2}_mM \oplus T_mM\otimes T_nN \oplus T^{\otimes 2}_nN$. A smooth map $f: M\to N$ is _poisson_ if the two Poisson structures are "$f$-related", but the diagonal map $M \to M\times M$ relates $\varpi\oplus0\oplus\varpi$ with $2\pi$, not $\varpi$.

Comment: (where $2\pi = 2\varpi$)

Comment: Huh. So I guess the situation is the following? The category $C$ of Poisson manifolds is equipped with a monoidal product such that the forgetful functor $C \to D$ to the category of smooth manifolds is monoidal, where $D$ has the usual product structure. A Poisson-Lie group is a monoid object in $C$ such that its image in $D$ is a group object. Yes? (This seems like a somewhat ugly setup.) 

Comment: Can't you make topological monoids that are groups but with discontinuous inverse? Like maybe an ordered group with a topology having the sets $(a,+\infty)$ as basis? It seems unlikely that there is a suitable functor $F:Top\to Top$.

Comment: Another kind of example: Let $C$ be the category of connected pointed analytic manifolds and let $D$ be the category of germs of such things (same objects but a map is a germ at the basepoint). There are lots of naturally occurring $D$-virtual group objects in $C$, such as the multiplicative monoid of all $n\times n$ matrices (basepoint is identity). Again, there seems to be no functor $F:C\to C$ in sight.

Comment: The first example is nice. (It seems that $F$ wants to be the functor "reverses the order," but in the category of posets.) In the second example, is the functor $C \to D$ faithful? 

Comment: It's faithful by uniqueness of analytic continuation, because I specified "connected" and "analytic". I didn't say whether I meant real or complex; either would work.