# Is it possible to define Hopf algebra as an object in the category of (associative) algebras?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras

I think this must be well-known, but I can't find references, so my apologies from the very beginning.

Consider first the notion of [bialgebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bialgebra). It is usually defined as an object $B$ in the category ${\tt Vect}_{\mathbb K}$ of vector spaces over a given field $\mathbb K$ with a system of morphisms in this category (multiplication, unit, comultiplication and counit) such that the multiplication and the unit turn $B$ into an associative algebra, the comultiplication and the counit turn $B$ into a coassociative coalgebra, and a system of commutative diagrams is provided for the compatibility. These diagrams can be understood as the requirement that the comultiplication and the couint are morphisms in the category ${\tt Alg}_{\mathbb K}$ of algebras (or, equivalently the multiplication and the unit are morphisms in the category ${\tt Coalg}_{\mathbb K}$ of coalgebras). So the whole definition can be understood as follows:

> a bialgebra is exactly a comonoid (=a coassociative coalgebra) in the category ${\tt Alg}_{\mathbb K}$ of associative algebras over $\mathbb K$ (or, equivalently, a monoid (=an associative algebra) in the category ${\tt Coalg}_{\mathbb K}$ of coassociative coalgebras over $\mathbb K$).

If we try to define Hopf algebras in the same way, then we face an obvious difficulty: the [diagram for antipode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_algebra) can't be immediately interpreted as a diagram in the category ${\tt Alg}_{\mathbb K}$ of associative algebras.

I wonder if there exists a trick for overcoming this? Is it possible that the diagram for antipode can be changed into equivalent diagrams in ${\tt Alg}_{\mathbb K}$ (so that we obtain a correct definition of Hopf algebras as objects in ${\tt Alg}_{\mathbb K}$)?

Comment: The antipode is an anti-algebra homomorphism. Is the opposite of an algebra well-defined in the category of algebras?

Comment: @darij grinberg: I thought, there is no problem with definition of opposite algebra. But the problem is with changing the digram for antipode so that it will be a diagram in ${\tt Alg}_{\mathbb K}$.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: The discussion in the comments at http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/10/07/group-hopf-algebra/ does not answer your question but it may still be useful (apologies if it just repeats things you had already considered)

Comment: Some more related discussion at [other](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1365/is-there-a-universal-group-object-answered-yes/1477#1477) [answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66474/).

Comment: I suspect the only ways to make this work are effectively the two trivial ways: (1) only work with commutative algebras, or (2) enlarge the category so that you include the necessary anti-algebra morphisms.